# 'teamviewer depends on (...)' while trying to install TeamViewer

Tags: dependencies, teamviewer

I recently got Ubuntu installed on my server, I wanted to install TeamViewer so i could easy manage the virtual machines, However, I get errors when installing it from App store?, And I also get errors, but more detailed on the terminal.

Error output:

```
tek@tek-G53SW:~/Download$ sudo dpkg -i ipts teamviewer_linux_x64.deb
dpkg: error processing ipts (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 142115 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace teamviewer7 7.0.9360 (using teamviewer_linux_x64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement teamviewer7 ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of teamviewer7:
 teamviewer7 depends on libc6-i386 (>= 2.7); however:
  Package libc6-i386 is not installed.
 teamviewer7 depends on lib32asound2; however:
  Package lib32asound2 is not installed.
 teamviewer7 depends on lib32z1; however:
  Package lib32z1 is not installed.
 teamviewer7 depends on ia32-libs; however:
  Package ia32-libs is not installed.
dpkg: error processing teamviewer7 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ipts
 teamviewer7
```

I tried to install it manually, but with no luck, I heard some others has this problems.
I am running Ubuntu 12.04 x64.

---

Error @ sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32asound2 lib32z1 ia32-libs :

```
tek@tek-G53SW:~/Download$ sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32asound2 lib32z1 ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
tek@tek-G53SW:~/Download$
```

---

More errors

```
tek@tek-G53SW:~/Download$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for tek:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  teamviewer7
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 81.9 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 142441 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing teamviewer7 ...
tek@tek-G53SW:~/Download$ sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32asound2 lib32z1 ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
lib32z1 is already the newest version.
libc6-i386 is already the newest version.
lib32asound2 is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
tek@tek-G53SW:~/Download$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 : Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gtk2-engines:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gtk2-engines-oxygen:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ibus-gtk:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libcups2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libcupsimage2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libfontconfig1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libgail-common:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libgphoto2-2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libgtk2.0-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libnss3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqt4-opengl:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqt4-qt3support:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqt4-scripttools:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqt4-svg:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqtgui4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqtwebkit4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: librsvg2-common:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libsane:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
tek@tek-G53SW:~/Download$
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the line saying "replacing" it looks as if TeamViewer is already installed.

If it isn't, run (in a terminal):

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32asound2 lib32z1 ia32-libs
```

and try installing the .deb with

```
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux_x64.deb
```

---

If nothing works, and only if nothing works, you can force installation, but you will most probably ***BREAK APT***:

```
sudo dpkg --force-depends -i teamviewer_linux_x64.deb
```

Note that this is ***far from ideal***.

Comment: Tried it, and it returned a error.
tek@tek-G53SW:~/Download$ sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32asound2 lib32z1 ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
tek@tek-G53SW:~/Download$

Comment: @Teknikk Please see edits to my post. Hopefully the new command works. If not, try `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch`.

Comment: @Teknikk Does my solution work?

Comment: Well, No, I added the data from the terminal that got some info when i did the commands you gave me.

Comment: Well, I got it to work using the non force method, After done the 3 steps, and got errors, i took a restart, and tried again, and then it worked, So i can finally manage this mechine on my other one.

Comment: Though it is not ideal, it worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is on the TeamViewer site.

Notes to Multiarch:
On newer 64-bit DEB-systems with Multiarch-support (Debian 7) teamviewer_linux_x64.deb cannot be installed because the package ia32-libs is not available anymore on these systems. In this case you can use teamviewer_linux.deb instead.

In case you get the error “**wrong architecture i386**” you have to execute the following command lines:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386

apt-get update
```

For further information: http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO

Answer (score 2):

I run teamviewer 7 on ubuntu 12.04 64 bit without any problems.

All that I did to install it was to download the file direct from the Teamviewer website selecting the correct version (i.e. Ubuntu 64 bit) and just opened the file and the software centre installed it for me without any issues.

But looking at your error output I would just install all the missing dependencies. Go into the Software Centre and search for each of the missing items and install them before trying to install teamviewer again. Remember in software centre to click on "show technical item" at the bottom left of the screen.

Hopefully this will work for you.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

For ubuntu 16.04 the following commands worked for me

`sudo apt-get install libz1:i386 libncurses5:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386 libstdc++6:i386`

Comment: after running the above I then had to run : 'sudo apt-get -f install'  That ran through and finished the teamviewer installation.  Note: I had already run the 'sudo dpkg -i ./teamviewer_13.0.9865_i386.deb command before doing all this.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option - not the best but it will get you working in Teamviewer.

If you have created a Teamviewer account via their website you can use the web login to remotely access other computers - it is only an outward connection so you can't use it to allow someone else to remotely access your computer but it will at least allow you to access others.

Sorry you are having so much trouble - all your new errors are above my knowledge base sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
sudo gdebi TEAMVIEWER_PACKAGE.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether teamviewer has already installed in your system by typing
`dpkg -l | grep team`

If so kindly remove it totally then install the supported dependencies and reinstall again using
`sudo dpkg --force-depends -i teamviewer_i386.deb`
You may find this article helpful.
http://bizgolive.com/blog/teamviewer-installation-in-lubuntu-from-command-line-dependency-error-fixed/